# Do they make 2.54mm 2P Crimpable Micro JST Female connectors?

Tags: hardware

This may be a dumb question but I need some (preferably with wires already attached) and I'm unable to find any like this. Everything I find has male crimps and female surface mount. That doesn't work for very well with my project because I do not have room in my project box for another board. I'm already cramped just adding the headers that I was planning to solder these wires to.

Here is what I'm looking for in the 1.25mm variety:
[image: 2P 1.25mm Crimpable JST Male connectors]

Comment: I don't believe "micro style" is a JST family designator.  You should start by figuring out which JST family you actually want, often they use two letter designations.  Also, voting to close as this has nothing specifically to do with Arduino, but is rather an entirely generic electronics question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found this product listing on Amazon:

[2.54mm spacing JST extension cable.](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01MQUJIYX)

It resembles the connector you've shown only slightly, but may be the only option out there.

And to contest the above statement, one that looks more like your objective:

[Another 2.54mm spacing JST cable](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00HG7GNL0)

There may be others. I used "jst 2.54 mm 2 pin female cable" as the search terms specifically in Amazon, other sources may have similar results.

Firing up the old Google again, using the last set of search terms, I've found an eBay listing:

[eBay product listing](http://www.ebay.com/itm/182174345865?rmvSB=true)

with the source in china. The photo appears correct, although the listing is for two cables, one male, one female, there is a third photo with the circuit board mount type connector.

This particular listing calls them a 2.5 mm connector, close enough? Perhaps a translation error.

[image: eBay listing photo]

Comment: The first is not the micro style. I don't think that is the same but I could be wrong. It looks much different. The second appears to be a typo because the picture shows male ends on the wires.

Comment: I don't think the first type would be interchangeable with the white connector style. I grabbed the second because of the text and didn't look at the image. I've added a third link, but it has caveats as well.